# error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1 while running cargo test --all

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

**Os**: macOS Big Sur

I'm facing the following error while running cargo tests while the build is succeeding.

**Package**: https://github.com/RustPython/RustPython

Command:

```
cargo test --all
```

Command `cargo build` doesn't throw any exception.

Error logs:

```
   Compiling libffi v1.0.1
   Compiling rustpython-jit v0.1.2 (/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/jit)
   Compiling rustpython v0.1.2 (/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-arch" "arm64" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.10ibwvzv3e49l775.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1253x86kfkxgqh2w.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.13gd08t800tm784s.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.14p9wnwl9pam5ujl.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.15e17o6bveg5koa6.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.17mujewb6k10id8k.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1a67xs61sj229iqf.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1ci2h9qeeeje0ik6.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1cmzqy3ro43zgsl5.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1dnexk54p6bq143f.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1e31m0nqihdfx5hb.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1e4tavcm7ugscqrd.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1emikuttnt1xip9x.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1eta79f60kanxjws.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1hayr2iv232dnoi6.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1huzgcxsirhwd331.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1jdul1odse6arzjz.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1kp92h8yxzzu0eov.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1m55byjo8aqq49zc.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1plr2gut2q06gwqk.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1r0h19gy6b54q79f.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1s8j2h2qxafcf3x8.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1satlrt2jdoiv4ey.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1vvhoeukrpxmv0pq.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1xe49efr9otpprwn.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.229y1orco2m4dyj8.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.22i642me58xe478c.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.22yxg2lkpcwbwqx.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.23c3y5v0ibs1r2fq.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.2478bzefed036zcv.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.24xhig5xkqgjnv7a.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.258jwdtpk3n29ru2.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.262rgc3v6z28qtsq.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.26mjhrskh3ru1tk9.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.276t6e8c7cnzg6wy.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.2bpnidflpn331uqr.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.2lboqix6b1cjj0jo.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.2m2yba3d9v8p6fyv.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.2n6eyp1zj3oa1kui.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.2ql5hnz2mtbmb7le.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.2rjcm2pt9uke0922.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.2s1wzpdirnzygv7e.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.2tbf8e6r9yt9czf5.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.2ttr38fcx39oazo7.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.2umn21lmb3qc9nxr.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.2uvshfalguw6hxx8.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.2w2ghiqspploxf0f.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.2w74b23mfhoia8ir.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.2wxy1kmtklu8y0w9.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.2x9iwja4h7bf6esl.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.35fuwnpoy3hc2gi7.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.378v5p8yoyjgyfyz.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.391sxamlpl6a96n9.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.39swqzjb6x4tkvcv.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.3botv3568qxh3591.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.3dhw8zhduh09e6r1.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.3flx495gko7kr9f9.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.3h4wy8wkv2xrirsf.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.3mm2wawuqp97kb7v.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.3ofzhlki1cafpfwl.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.3pjsd8hbre1ap5qd.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.3rwk183rvg7z9yca.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.3srtodjtz7bmdola.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.3xlrku5wblas6gnr.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.3yy87npargho7bsd.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.3z5naev9k6lae39q.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.3z9gvqp1n32fcpsx.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.3zjs7qt7onoigcne.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.3zyfqkyu7djvtze2.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.423bys4dlvrx8mvq.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.426c4cdyhetxwb5w.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.42kzw8c6fadp0tby.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.44bge1cbwp7t2tkx.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.49gtvrz6zpsigsfc.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.49lpjq6zqkjbvmne.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4gi8gsjxezpv3s06.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4gilgzakkbsi3l3e.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4iwdwkt6d9cng8m2.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4jodrvbiqg7w437z.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4kybga5bhkscrs8c.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4lekp20xf8bz0r94.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4m0obk2qh4uzuwsj.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4nlx000cuo8jnqlt.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4ofwdpd0cukslkz0.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4q725i3d0yxgop7v.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4qo1sfh57tihaadg.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4rh1b2hcqpcdq3a3.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4s2ymju7it0okdeb.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4ust4yu9nvanfhdf.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4vfd4l254fl8v4dd.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4xc7hv9qb2t7d616.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4xqxqqk3fs5kqtfz.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4y6jbmqopamez3c.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.4yhh8wqcvrop0hx3.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.54jq72kupaotxmzo.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.56zmipy278cdawgn.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.58zht470tb0hjgt1.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.5dzonsas4ynzribc.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.5g4vw0c8dqjw8h37.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.5gh4c861meudgewi.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.6bjt88zjkzd9tt3.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.7as0apovcqc5gub.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.cae7y3juuwiitl1.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.ifacragtyfrbb42.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.jz4h5hg9g0tz6mi.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.kmvxofl9saiovs2.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.nhc3hxxj09rktbm.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.prm338a1k8u52l1.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.q4rx7xjh7rujfgy.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.rztn7f71t7dz6pf.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.ygusbdg7fggss41.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.ykouej5rwx3lr5s.rcgu.o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5.1jyvo8pa9soqa56a.rcgu.o" "-L" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/build/libffi-sys-652628ec5b194c33/out/libffi-root/lib" "-L" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/build/libffi-sys-652628ec5b194c33/out/libffi-root/lib64" "-L" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libapprox-30ccea96c4acf95a.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libtest-06ff11d645105e2b.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libterm-f05ecaeca66814e6.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libgetopts-6ad0d034fc8e15c7.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libunicode_width-c4beacdc35405cb8.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc_std_workspace_std-fc0f4647def297a8.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/librustpython_jit-2e831fdd027df713.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/liblibffi-fd0ec330aa459432.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libabort_on_panic-caaa79ca88d47ba3.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/liblibffi_sys-5863f41be7d2bccd.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libcranelift_jit-2c55f3ef4f39d959.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libregion-197ded681c450d8b.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libmach-a93a18ecabd99da0.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/liberrno-0a3c0f746fd85f07.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/liblibc-66d4f3764ade8a61.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libcranelift_native-08015c03c8f0902a.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libcranelift_module-0691469284a7b208.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libanyhow-ef3e763f417c2d7a.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libcranelift-032d6c244a218970.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libcranelift_frontend-5ce9f83164bb63c5.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libcranelift_codegen-7362291990ed24ba.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libregalloc-57353d751727d8ce.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/librustc_hash-ab040f1fd6a07e95.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libsmallvec-99a5132b3a108cbf.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libtarget_lexicon-abfb03971829d1d1.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libcranelift_codegen_shared-453aa55f38698ce1.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libthiserror-53c05dc94aa30ff9.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/liblog-3f8f67c165fe661d.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libcfg_if-c71a5d33f98d84bb.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libcranelift_bforest-b2a7cbdbbb4b7b2e.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libcranelift_entity-5d71031a19adbb58.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/librustpython_bytecode-44e562fca4e24da9.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libbincode-7a343aa511b2a28b.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/liblz4_flex-99575d661e0f318f.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libnum_complex-fde276a77140cb97.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libnum_bigint-a611dddfa4c568f4.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libnum_integer-7f325eb6a21e8c2e.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libnum_traits-4df9bc95fb47d436.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libitertools-886b111642563542.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libeither-3e64107fd8334906.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libbstr-c7fc013625c0f979.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/liblazy_static-d1f48f17eb43777c.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libregex_automata-21a890d37c6a8dcc.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libserde-2ae11beb1fcdc4df.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libmemchr-53a80abe7ced0f1a.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/libbitflags-9f56f92ce6089ce7.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libstd-000cdec9267bfd7b.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libpanic_unwind-2669f3cbce8358f4.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libobject-86461a1c60728ccb.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libaddr2line-f17574752cb5ddba.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libgimli-3bb606c936cc0d28.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libstd_detect-8139a4b0cda20184.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc_demangle-ea0823eca3e9abf9.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libhashbrown-4f19e1259f6028e7.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-435daca85b8e10b5.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libunwind-d73085abefd284c6.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libcfg_if-e6a09ca0044b34e5.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/liblibc-e07333f48f53c71e.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/liballoc-2a49b0d9fbc7a459.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-b66dda66aafe36c9.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libcore-34d0b58da984bf31.rlib" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libcompiler_builtins-01275baa20724171.rlib" "-liconv" "-lSystem" "-lresolv" "-lc" "-lm" "-liconv" "-L" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib" "-o" "/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/integration-59c3340cf4710de5" "-Wl,-dead_strip" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/build/libffi-sys-652628ec5b194c33/out/libffi-root/lib64'
          ld: in /Users/hardikkhandelwal/Projects/rust/RustPython/target/debug/deps/liblibffi_sys-5863f41be7d2bccd.rlib(closures.o), archive member 'closures.o' with length 17440 is not mach-o or llvm bitcode for architecture arm64
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
 
 
error: aborting due to previous error
error: could not compile `rustpython-jit`
 
To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Comment: Please add the full error. We can't help you if we don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Please find the detailed error logs in the following pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/6WDSp7kR